# Does Modern Science's Law of Causation confirm Christianity's Doctrine of Creation as stated in Genesis 1:1 and Acts 17:24?

Tags: creation, science, atheism, logic, doctrine

The discoveries in modern science by Einstein and Hubble assert that the universe is expanding, and that if the "clock" were rolled back, the universe would come to a "Singularity Point." They stop, scientifically, and cannot speak as to where the "plasma" of that Point came from. But they do raise the inescapable need for a "Cause."

The scientific Law requires one:  *Every thing that came to be must have a Cause for its coming onto being.* (Law of Causation) And common sense dictates: *ex nihilo, nihil fit* (From nothing, nothing comes.)

Of course, science does not name the Source (God) even though it does require a Cause with the attributes of a "Cause" that matches the Christian God.

**In the Beginning God** is the beginning of the revelation by God to mankind. In this statement lies the Cause, purpose, and meaning of all creation! And this revelatory FACT is the basis for the Christian doctrine in Christianity.

This query asks nothing about the mode or method of Creation nor the process of speciation, nor the development of stars, planes, galaxies, etc. But only focuses on the original **Source, Cause, Creator** of this vast universe. And if modern science gives any **factual input** that would help settle this dilemma that perplexes the human mind. This question asks neither for opinion or traditional folklore, but only for the application of **scientific Laws** recognized by modern researchers, that confirm the biblical Doctrine of Creation.

This question is ***neither philosophical nor sociological*** but references well-accepted *scientific facts* in relates them to well-taught *Christian doctrines* in Christianity.

Comment: I suspect this question is overly broad. In general, the answer is "no", but there is not a straight-forward answer. I can state that there is no other rational explanation for life, but explaining *why* that is so is not straight forward. I could go so far as to note that a historical reading of Genesis 1-11 is the most scientifically consistent, but again, same problem. In any case, someone opposed to God is going to believe what they want to believe, regardless of whether those beliefs are rational.

Comment: Faith is the incontrovertible rebuttal to unbelief. 'Logical' arguments depend on the 'logic' of the arguer. But faith has a different logic altogether from the unbeliever. There is no 'proof' that will convince the unbeliever - until he sees, for himself, the wrath of God : and experiences it.

Comment: @Nigel - Rules of logic are universal.  One does not make up his own set of rules. Many misconceptions of "faith" are bandied about; but true faith is not contrary to logic or reason or plain thinking...God made them all.  "Come, let us reason together"--God.  There is no doubt the Holy Spirit must work on the "will" of a man, but He is not unfriendly to wisdom in the process.

Comment: @Monitor - Is the Doctrine of Origins (Creator) no longer a major Christian doctrine? And is not this an important area of contention between Christians and unbelievers that Christians need to be able to answer to keep the faith confidently?

Comment: @Moderator - See the new title.  Is the Doctrine of Creation (Origins) no longer a major Christian doctrine?  And is not this an important bone of contention between Christians and non-christians? Where does this question fail?

Comment: @raygrant it's not a "Universal Doctrine" if that's what you mean.  I'd have to imagine you're talking about "Creationism" or "Intelligent Design" which not all Christians are required or apt to accept.   If you specify which denomination you're talking about it usually helps.

Comment: @PeterTurnerThe question does not address "how" the Creation took place, which as you say, is still controversial.  But thus post only deals with the question of there being a BEGINNING and therefore the necessity of a CAUSE of it all.  And if science confirms (what is already revealed in Scripture) it seems to deal a blow to Atheist's "no Cause" scenario, or does it?  That is the question.

Comment: "Should this give naturalists pause to reconsider the Doctrine of Creation, if they are to give credence and allegiance to modern science?" This is still an opinion question.

Comment: @ curiousdannii - The paragraph in question is summarily deleted. Okay now?

Comment: "Since this important fact ... would it not be a blessing and advantage ...?" is still a question of opinion! Please see [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: @ curiousdannii - Edited out  the offending sentence, and emboldened "fact" requirement.  Also see Question 92754, where "naturalism" references were allowed on Christianity S.E.   Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I am an ex-atheist Christian. I think I can safely promise you that no line of reasoning presented by another person will convince an atheist against his will.  Logical "proofs" of the existence of God don't really work, because they might tell us that a God exists, but they don't tell us enough about what kind of God exists.

The only thing I can offer is this argument which went through my own mind before I was converted, and which certainly helped to pave the way;

"You decided to be an atheist because you said there was 'no evidence' for the existence of God. But that is not a sufficient reason. There is no evidence against him either. If there is no evidence either way, that just leaves the question open.

In other words, you cannot claim that your decision to become an atheist was forced upon you by rational necessity. It was a choice. It was an expression of personal preference.

If it was your personal preference, then you can be held morally accountable for it. You wouldn't be able to offer any excuse. You need to think about that."

Comment: @StephenDisraeliThe line of reasoning that brought you to God is amazing!  But I imagine that you will discover that there are "many" other ways that men have come to believe in the existence of God.  The "Will" is definitely the final arbiter of the soul.  But the way the Will is transformed is multitudinal ministers and priests will aver.  For example, Anthony Flew, a confirmed skeptic, was convinced to believe in God, by the obvious Design in the universe.  His Will was  brought around by scientific evidence.  Others are convinced by the compassion shown by the self-sacrificing Lamb of God.

Comment: @StephenDisraeliUsually a person's Will is transformed by the evidence gleaned from an individual's Epistemology: rationalism, evidentialism, empiricism,  mysticism, etc. This question wonders about the effect of scientific empiricism on the atheistic ideology. Does it establish a "fact" by which the Atheist can compare ideas?

Answer (score -1):

**Syllogisms** are a common device in the discipline of logic that helps scholars arrive at truth, as well as correct erroneous thinking.  Here is a syllogism that is applicable to the dilemma of Atheism, and helps refute its posture as a philosophy denying a Creator:

1. If the Atheism with no Creator is true, there could be no atheists.
2. But atheists exist.
3. Therefore Atheism is not true.

This is a "**Denying the consequent** logical exercise of the form: if A, then not B; but B, therefore not A.  It is a valid proposition. And its premises are solid.

**Explanation**  The Atheist philosophy posits no Creator, Source, or Cause for the origin of the Universe. They presume that everything in the Universe came from Nothing!

But "From nothing, nothing comes." (*ex nihilo, nihil fit*).  There could be no universe, no life, and *no atheists* in existence, without a Cause(Creator). But living Atheists do exist! So there must have been a Cause, after all.

Any philosophy that denies the existence of a Cause would be a false worldview. Atheism is therefore a false worldview (philosophy).  *Nihil sine Deo.* "Nothing exists without God."

Einstein and Hubble showed scientifically that the material universe had a beginning, and Steven Hawking showed that Time had a beginning. And the **Law of Causation** requires a Cause (Source, Creator).  Therefore, Atheism which denies a Cause, is flawed fatally! Atheism is *not* a logical, reasonable, intellectual worldview.  And Christians need not cower in their presence. Modern science opens the door for a Creator of the universe, and slams the door when Atheists try to enter!

The "cause" that science demands for the Creation of the universe, has the Attributes of the Christian (biblical) God: It must be outside of time (eternal), and outside of physical matter (spirit).  Eternal Spirit is the God that Jesus revealed to the woman at the well (John 4:24).

Comment: There is nothing Christian in this answer : no Christian experience, no Christian faith. It is merely philosophical - and not very well informed philosophy at that. One could do better just mulling through some Wikipedia articles.

Comment: @Nigel - This valid syllogism (as atheist have admitted) gives Christians a respite from the anxiety of atheistic attacks, and proves to Christian believers that it is logical to believe in a Cause, (Creator)! And that it is not logical to believe in no Cause.

Comment: My Christian experience and my Christian faith are a stronger foundation than what you propose. It is illogical, to me, to muddle terminology thus - '_proves_ to Christian _believers_ that it is _logical_ to _believe_ . . . '. I believe because I have been convicted of my own sins and have been made aware of the wrath to come and have received the knowledge of Christ Jesus, my Lord.

Comment: @Nigel - There are many ways people come to faith in Jesus (e.g. "the goodness of God leads to...).  One way is a recognition of the human condition.  But another battlefield that some struggle with is logic and reasoning (mind is a part of the human makeup) and they need Answers in that area,  This is for them.

Comment: . . . _the world, by wisdom, knew not God_ . . . . 1 Corinthians 1:21.

Comment: This syllogism contains two premises.  Both are sound (true statements).  And the conclusion is a logical deduction (Denying the consequent).  There is no fallacy of the undetermined middle.  The Cause of the universe is a necessity, and the atheistic philosophies (no matter hoe defined) fail by contradicting this reality.  As credentialed astrophysicists have noted, there must be a Source of the "singularity point", outside of the physical universe, Atheism to the contrary. Do not the Christian religions all place this in their creedal doctrines? (Catholic, Protestant, Orthodox)

Comment: @Nigel J-There has been much fuss about the syllogism mentioned, and much backlash. BUT none have been able to assail the syllogism itself!  Its deductive conclusion is too certain, and no one wants to deal with it because of its penetrating application to reality. It clearly shows the need for a Creator  to explain the existence of everything.  It show that the NoGod posture is lacking, and the YesGod worldview is more than credible. Thus Creation is part of the creeds of Catholicism, Protestantism, Greek Orthodoxy (and Islam), and thoughtful Scientists.

Comment: "All truth is God's truth!"  Wisdom from science, logic, philosophy (epistemology, metaphysics, ethics, aesthetics, et al.), history, reflects the awesome All-knowing attributes of God.  So it is true that they would all point to a Creator when accurately researched and appealed to.

Comment: @Nigel-_There is nothing Christian in this answer_---If A-theism is shown to be false, by default Theism is the only possible alternative. And from  Bible College teaching we learned that Theism is the basis of Christianity! Christianity is, therefore, in this answer. Without Theism there is no Christianity.

Comment: @Nigel-_the world, by Wisdom, knew not God _ (1 Cor. 1:21) We know that context determines the meaning and use of a word.  "Wisdom" in your verse is a definite referral to the Greek philosophies (Sophism, Epicurianism, Neoplatonism, etc.).  Paul's statement is NOT negating _apologetics_.  This same writer went to Athens and used "metaphysical arguments" in speaking to scholars on Areopagus!  (cosmological, teleological, anthropological arguments)  AND he used them successfully because enough people believed to start a church there.  A scholar, Dionysius, was converted, and a number of others!